# How to convert the following date format "1st-May-2013" to "2013-05-01"

Tags: java, java-8

How to convert the date format `1st-May-2013` to `2013-05-01` 
, `10th-Jun-2002` to `2002-06-10` and `2nd-Apr-1996` to `1996-04-02`.

Notice that the input dates contain the ordinal part (e.g. `1st` etc).

Comment: Actually, it's interesting because the input format uses things like `1st`, `2nd` etc. Not a total duplicate, but the OP didn't point out the difference here.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use split() and separate the "-" then you would get an array of three where the order is day, month, year. Then you could just get the year value first, then find a way to identify the month into numbers and just grab the first single char from day. If the day is less than 10 then add a 0 to the front.

Comment: @Catherine what's the advantage of doing this over using one of the standard library classes that was specifically designed for this problem, handles all special cases without problems and is tested and robust?

Comment: @Ben maybe he doesn't want to use a library? haha you're right though

Comment: @Catherine When it is part of the standard java, then it isn't a library. Seriously, suggesting to parse dates manually, that is ... not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Ordinal part is not considered by the existings formatter of `LocalDate` which is `DateTimeFormatter`, so you need to remove the ordinal part, and then parse with the good pattern

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[]strs = {"1st-May-2013", "10th-Jun-2002", "2nd-Apr-1996"};       
    for(String str : strs){
        LocalDate d = ordinalStringToDate(str);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
private static LocalDate ordinalStringToDate(String str){
     return LocalDate.parse(str.replaceAll("(st|nd|rd|th)", ""), 
                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy"));
}
```

*Pattern* :

- `d` is for the day number
- `MMM` is for the month short litteral (`MMMM` if for full month name)
- `yyyy` fot the year number

---

### [***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/g3DbFO)

Comment: This is a quick method that actually addresses parsing problem, but for robust implementation this probably require regex.

Comment: @Jay I don't get why people are always so keen on using regex for every simple thing. `replaceAll` already uses regex, azro defined a perfectly fitting capture group for the use-case and everything is covered. The only thing that could blow up is a wrong input string and that is something that should not be handled here but a step earlier - and also was not part of the question.